# how to get previous working day in windows command (via powershell)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to get the previous working day in a dos batch file, as the files to handle has the date in the filenames, under `yyyymmdd` and `ddmmmyy` format.

It seems, according to [Dos to get next day date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094772/dos-to-get-next-day-date) , this is rather complex in pure dos command.

So I turned to calling powershell in dos. so far I get till here:

```
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.ToString^('yyyyMMdd'^)`) DO SET yyyymmdd=%%i
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.ToString^('ddMMMyy'^)`)  DO SET ddmmmyy=%%
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date^=$date.AddDays^(-1^)^; $date.ToString^('yyyyMMdd'^)`) DO SET yyyymmddEOD=%%i 
FOR /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date^=$date.AddDays^(-1^)^; $date.ToString^('ddMMMyy'^)`)  DO SET ddmmmyyEOD=%%
```

by doing so, `yyyymmdd` and `ddmmmyy` is today's date, while `yyyymmddEOD` and `ddmmmyyEOD` is the day before.

However, what shall I do, if i need to get the previous "working day"?

By *working day*, the best solution would probably like [Excel WorkDay function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33), `WORKDAY(start_date, days, [holidays])`, but for now, for the sake of simplicity, let's just take Monday to Friday as *Working Day*. So that if today is Tuesday, then the *previous working day* is Monday, while if today is Monday, then the *previous working day* is previous Friday.

There's an example on how to get the "next working day" at [Powershell Golf: Next business day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018873/powershell-golf-next-business-day) , however, it seems run under powershell interface. I tried but did not succeed turn it into a dos batch file.

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](http://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: "Working day" isn't precisely defined in your question, and might depend on a number of factors specific to your customer's needs.

Comment: I would try to run another powershell command to get the number of the weekday using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111557/using-powershell-how-do-you-get-the-weekday-number/15116228) anwers and if it turns out that "yesterday" has been a Sunday you run the command you use to get the date of yesterday not with `addDays(-1)` but `addDays(-3)` to get the date of Friday. If you just want to have the weekday, you can just return `Friday` if yesterday was either Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 how to combine the powershell and dos command together?

Comment: How you do it already in the code above. You should be getting the result from the powershell command into a variable as you do already and then use the variable to generate the next command from which you should be getting the desired output.

Comment: What about public holidays? do you want them to be regarded either for retrieving the previous working day? if so, date/time maths (by PowerShell) is not sufficient, you need to use something that relies on a calendar...

Comment: @aschipfl that's too complex, probably have to give up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit more readable. You can adjust as you need. No escaping characters are necessary.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set days=-0 -1 -3
set formats=yyyyMMdd ddMMMyy
set ps=[DateTime]::Now.AddDays(%%b).ToString('%%a')

REM Get today, yesterday, and three days ago in two date formats
for %%a in (%formats%) do (
    for %%b in (%days%) do (
        for /f %%p in ('"powershell %ps%"') do set date-%%a%%b=%%p
    )
)

REM If today is Monday, subtract 3 for EOD, else subtract 1
for /f %%a in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.ToString('ddd')"') do (
    if "%%a"=="Mon" (set sub=3) else (set sub=1)
)

REM Change the variable names if you want
set yyyymmdd=%date-yyyymmdd-0%
set ddmmmyy=%date-ddmmmyy-0%
set yyyymmddEOD=!date-yyyymmdd-%sub%!
set ddmmmyyEOD=!date-ddmmmyy-%sub%!

REM Output your variables
set yyyymmdd
set ddmmmyy
```

Output (for today, Wed, Oct 12):

```
yyyymmdd=20161012
yyyymmddEOD=20161011
ddmmmyy=12Oct16
ddmmmyyEOD=11Oct16
```

**EDIT**

Here is an even simpler way of doing it. It seemed more obvious to me after a night of sleep. =) I didn't replace what I wrote above because it would have invalidated your comment, but I thought it might be useful still, so I added it.

```
@echo off

REM If today is Monday, subtract 3 for EOD, else subtract 1
if %date:~0,3%==Mon (set EOD=-3) else (set EOD=-1)

REM Get today and last EOB in two date formats
for %%a in (yyyyMMdd ddMMMyy) do (
    for /f %%p in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.ToString('%%a')"') do set %%a=%%p
    for /f %%p in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(%EOD%).ToString('%%a')"') do set %%aEOD=%%p
)

REM Output your variables
set yyyymmdd
set ddmmmyy
```

Answer (score 1):

A small script, I made up would look like this:

```
 for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.AddDays^(-1^)^; $date.getWeekDay^(^)^;`) DO ( 
SET weekday=%%i
Goto outer
)
:outer
set weekday=%weekday:,=%
"set weekend="
if "x%weekday%"=="xSunday" set weekend=1
if "x%weekday%"=="xSaturday" set weekend=1
if defined weekend (
echo Friday
) Else (
echo %weekday%
)
pause
```

This would echo the weekday of yesterday or if yesterday was either Saturday or Sunday it would echo "Friday"

EDIT:
Beeing curious for myself I wrote a version giving out the date if that is needed:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.AddDays^(-1^)^; $date.getWeekDay^(^)^;`) DO ( 
SET weekday=%%i
Goto:outer
)
:outer
set weekday=%weekday:,=%
if "x%weekday%"=="xSaturday" (
    for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.AddDays^(-2^)^; $date.toString^('yyyyMMdd'^)^;`) DO ( 
    SET weekday=%%i
    )
Goto:echoWD
) Else (
 if "x%weekday%"=="xSunday" (
        for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.AddDays^(-3^)^; $date.toString^('yyyyMMdd'^)^;`) DO ( 
    SET weekday=%%i
    )
 Goto:echoWD
 ) Else (
     for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date.AddDays^(-1^)^; $date.ToString^('yyyyMMdd'^)^;`) DO ( 
     SET weekday=%%i
         )
 Goto:echoWD
     )
)
:echoWD
echo %weekday%
pause
```

**Notice:** The output will be in your language, so you might need to change `xSunday` to `xSonntag` in Germany for example.

Is probably easier to do but never touch a running system ;)